# Relationship between $2^{m}$ immediate greater than $3^{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know if there exists any formula for deriving $2^{m}$ which would be in the close proximity of $3^{n}$, meaning to get $2^{m-1} < 3^{n} < 2^{m}, m,n \in \mathbb{N} - \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$.

In fact the requirement is to derive $m$ for any value which $n$ might take up!

Looking for a good solution!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$$m = \left \lceil{\frac{\ln 3^n}{\ln 2}}\right \rceil$$

This is just the solution, but as to how it comes about, just use the properties of log

Comment: You can get properly sized floor/ceiling operators (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.